# Integrate sum of functions vs sum of integrated functions with scipy solve_ivp

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, integral

So I was wondering: Shouldn’t the sum of the integrals of some functions be equivalent to the integral of the sum of the functions?

Here I integrate three arbitrary functions with the help of `scipy`’s [`solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html):

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def fun1(t, y): return 0.5 * y
def fun2(t, y): return 0.05 * y**2
def fun3(t, y): return y + 5

sol1 = solve_ivp(fun1, [0, 5], [2], rtol=1e-10, atol=1e-10)
sol2 = solve_ivp(fun2, [0, 5], [2], rtol=1e-10, atol=1e-10)
sol3 = solve_ivp(fun3, [0, 5], [2], rtol=1e-10, atol=1e-10)

print(f'{sol1.y[0][-1]} + {sol2.y[0][-1]} + {sol3.y[0][-1]} = {sol1.y[0][-1]+sol2.y[0][-1]+sol3.y[0][-1]}')
```

this gives:

```python
24.36498792283038 + 4.0000000000803775 + 1033.8921138100272 = 1062.257101732938
```

But on the other hand:

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def fun(t, y): return (0.5 * y) + (0.05 * y**2) + (y + 5)

sol = solve_ivp(fun, [0, 5], [2], rtol=1e-10, atol=1e-10)

print(f'{sol.y[0][-1]}')
```

gives:

```python
233176411972824.97
```

Can any of you smart people show me my error in thinking? Is my maths wrong or do I have to implement this task differently in Python? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. The initial values are inconsistent. You have to sum initial values too.
2. If you sum solutions of

```
dy/dt = -y 
dy/dt = y 
y(0)=1
```

you do not get the solution of

```
dy/dt = 0
```

you get

```
cos(t) + y^t
```

But

```
dy/dt = t
dy/dt = t
```

you do get solution of

```
dy/dt = 2t
```

So the code below gives consistent results.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def fun1(t, y): return 0.5 * t
def fun2(t, y): return 0.05 * t**2
def fun3(t, y): return t + 5

sol1 = solve_ivp(fun1, [0, 5], [2], rtol=1e-10, atol=1e-10)
sol2 = solve_ivp(fun2, [0, 5], [2], rtol=1e-10, atol=1e-10)
sol3 = solve_ivp(fun3, [0, 5], [2], rtol=1e-10, atol=1e-10)

print(f'{sol1.y[0][-1]} + {sol2.y[0][-1]} + {sol3.y[0][-1]} = {sol1.y[0][-1]+sol2.y[0][-1]+sol3.y[0][-1]}')


def fun(t, y): return (0.5 * t) + (0.05 * t**2) + (t + 5)

sol = solve_ivp(fun, [0, 5], [6], rtol=1e-10, atol=1e-10)

print(f'{sol.y[0][-1]}')
```

**Update**

Generally, you solve `dy/dt=f(y,t)`. The case `dy/dt=g(t)` differs from `dy/dt=h(y)`.

If you do no have `y` in the right side you can simply sum equations

```
dy1/dt=g1(t) 
dy2/dt=g2(t)
=>
d(y1 + y2)/dt=g1(t) + g2(t)
```

make substitution `y = dy1+dy2` and get

```
y/dt=g1(t) + g2(t)
```

And everything goes as you expect. You can apply `solve_ivp` to the whole function or to its parts.

If you have `y` in the right side

```
dy1/dt=h1(y1)
dy2/dt=h2(y2)
```

and sum you get

```
d(y1 + y2)/dt=h1(y1) + h2(y2)
```

and substitution `y = y1 + y2` leads you nowhere. So you cannot split the right side for such case into parts to get the whole result by separate integration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Indeed your remark regarding initial values was very valuable. I hope you don’t mind one question: In fun1, fun2, and fun3, why do you change the variable from `y` to `t`? Doesn’t this change the integration dramatically? In fact, I tried to stick to the documentation of [solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html). There in the _Examples_ section, `y` is always used in the exemplary equations.

Comment: @Sebastian, `y->t`  changes equations dramatically. 
Updated answer.